# Are Data Member and Entity Member the same thing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, odata

I am getting following error while executing API, swagger shows that business unit is not mapped. I want to find out is that a business unit is data member or entity member.

"The specified type member 'BusinessUnit' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: we cannot help you much without actual code. refer here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am just asking, is data member same as entity member ? and I fond the answer. it is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, I found the answer by searching on the internet. There is no difference between data member and entity member.